# Is this proof for completeness of regular model checking correct?

Tags: formal-methods, model-checking, denotational-semantics

In "Calculational Design of A Regular Model Checker by Abstract Interpretation" by Patrick Cousot ([link](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271538/1-s2.0-S0304397521X00175/1-s2.0-S0304397521000712/am.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEDoaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIAy43KUYt0CSlRMymVDKX5nNg4Im5h8m9JFMvupoflvgAiEA9zjMChE6gp2480dT4Yuf3K5iexHFA41AztRv1VhflTAqswUIExAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDJ2GiosxRDPWh0589SqQBcO%2BwRiBXIpL5gpChNB4l%2BiB4bTJHoCVeMSnM4PJGk%2BtsVZgd8xOjr1heU3gRkp4Z4YUFyvahDSTAwYBYswxnyVI88F7X0chpIlXnDZKkC6CaVwfflU9UoBvrXIWhyRjkcQ2EfN%2BK347TVSk83%2FH81mTop2SLSOGmsj1HnVeULxGqkG2ADNUK1EI%2BZzKsDCuj6Uh0qiwQJ5rcsf%2FT2SwBLsA4DLRi7zYnmMtHwAgU0p2eyKXA6BgRXaXKHTebXkb%2FPiaQwS1FQk14zCKSQ8rxNsL9siymzC64AyJeU3orvH9m3n4ebhzzp%2FK%2FOlKNzMfZQGxC5IFrhkXxfGVXb6ECCMAglzy%2FtAsJSWEJPbTKrhDf1pEsVEH974o2x7VGgb5WTtUzQgdpzvAZAtCXzKkmf0fnBndrhHoBPsw46Pqez5UhKEYu0gpastbOWjQ9jsRAiWuo5flU%2BgFm3YPuanj5X5SSYxNnor0llQxRSE%2BmpsllcXTiwHRazZFOlnAjhQp6LqLvj3HMdoFX%2FCNdSAsrutBCI%2F%2B%2FA1hhmuBaPNIgCXE%2F1He0PWUFaoldesgVolcrlbOI3T48E5I4IEDPVNm9HjWpapIQhjGOGxnmfgzzlhmFdNPJ0YHGFJJwJpYqhj5Zs6A%2BzZb%2FnQvM0P7sbG5sQZ%2Fg18nZR6H%2FMI7uW5%2FkpCQUjj6Y5WMl%2Bj8BM30TMSbO08s3%2BlRNM1ptT0Vmfjlzuy9Es7dt13n3TRAguumew4TGwVZehBrfovSujShDWL1MbqiyQPXccQVNBzE7LbZocylL%2Bb6H6rVlBhDthuABQdQZzoLYcm9DSKyIiyYN3qtWZ2X5Jm1PtEKtFE02XxSsNMQqhumXigwIyw8PnXM5O3zMM2KzKcGOrEBIrh799WQ4z%2FffCNtT5b23CqHOjh%2FufjKg88VhTV8T2vN%2BkoanwQjWWn7BD%2FNn24%2BHDVLixpyLeoRXsgXR4AGdzed%2FSNkilGg7WXZ9ORGQGhU3toPiZBb7W11BPQ7Ewnnu%2F2RgMsngM7Llu7YXCYdvA03oEz00lAMYbHI01lx3i9KD%2BFW71IwCk12i%2F1psHTA%2Fepl%2FKSyoJ%2BrxL33nhNJjYFx49%2BEC9fS%2B4YVAy2r4Po5&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230902T104541Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYV6RQ7C4V%2F20230902%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=23377b3c55c9502458ed9b46dffae48a48ca05af5304792f324016bed7e382da&hash=4976455039c10c90da8ab3540402838f4e6948ad1d75434d67bbfc70005f1956&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0304397521000712&tid=pdf-99852bf2-0226-4541-ac44-c7ae34ae9a59&sid=9a87506790cef749197806e9fff95e2c19edgxrqb&type=client)), on page 15 it can be seen that to prove the completeness of regular model checking (**Definition 12**) with respect to model checking (**Definition 7**), Cousot is trying to prove this proposition in **Lemma 15**:

$$\{\underline \rho \} \times \mathcal{S}^* [ \mathsf{P}] \subseteq \mathsf{prefix}(\mathcal{S}^r[\mathsf{R}\bullet(?:\mathit{T})^*]) \Rightarrow \mathcal{S}^* [ \mathsf{P}] \subseteq \mathcal{M}[\mathsf{P}]\mathsf{R} $$

I think that the given proof does not prove this proposition, but it proves the reverse of this proposition instead, which has been proved in **Lemma 14**.

Does anyone agree with me? Or am I getting something wrong here?

Also, I think that the statement of **Lemma 14** is wrong. First, I have not seen the definition of $\mathcal{M}$ that does not take $\underline{\rho}$ (an initial environment) in the paper, and second, if we assume that $\mathcal{M}[\mathsf{P}] \mathsf{R}$ is an abbreviation of $\mathcal{M}[\mathsf{P}] \langle \underline{\rho}, \mathsf{R}\rangle$ (which is defined) then it should be considered that $\mathcal{M}[\mathsf{P}] \langle \underline{\rho}, \mathsf{R}\rangle$ contains $\pi$ (prefix traces) while $\mathsf{prefix}(\mathcal{S}^r [\mathsf{R}\bullet(?:\mathit{T})^*])$ contains $\langle \underline{\rho},\pi \rangle$ (pairs consisting of an initial environment and a prefix trace), so they are not comparable or in other words, the inclusion never holds.